# When installing idevicerestore I get errors saying I'm missing libraries

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I've been trying to install Idevicerestore on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I keep getting errors of missing libraries, and it's frustrating trying to install them one by one.

This is what comes up after running `./autogen.sh`

```
root@dyrexion-Aspire-E1-531:/home/dyrexion/Desktop/idevicerestore-master# ./autogen.sh
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: linking file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:33: installing './compile'
configure.ac:8: installing './missing'
src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libirecovery... yes
checking for libimobiledevice... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libimobiledevice-1.0 >= 1.1.6) were not met:

No package 'libimobiledevice-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libimobiledevice_CFLAGS
and libimobiledevice_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I keep getting different errors about missing packages each time I install one.

Is there anything I can do to install all libs needed at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prerequisites are listed in the `README` or alternatively on the [github idevicerestore project page](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/idevicerestore)

```
Development Packages of:
    libimobiledevice
    libirecovery
    libusbmuxd
    libplist
    libzip
    openssl
```

On Debian-based systems, development packages generally use a `-dev` suffix. The following packages should be available from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
libimobiledevice-dev libusbmuxd-dev libplist-dev libzip-dev
```

`openssl` is a bit of a special case - you will need to choose between

```
libcurl4-gnutls-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
libcurl4-nss-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
libcurl4-openssl-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)
```

As far as I know, Ubuntu repositories do not contain a pre-built version of `libirecovery` so you will need to locate and build that yourself

Comment: pardon me, but i`m not quite sure how to execute those. are they file directories or something?

Comment: For `libirecovery` I don't know - you will need to locate its source code and build instructions. The others may be installed using `apt` or `apt-get` e.g. `sudo apt install libimobiledevice-dev libusbmuxd-dev libplist-dev libzip-dev`

Comment: thank you very much, it worked like a charm...  :D   how do I rate?